# Multiplication by rectangular matrix with orthonormal columns does not change norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ complex matrix with orthonormal columns $(m \ge n)$. Let $x \in \mathbb{C}^m$ be in the column space of $A$. I want to show that $||x||_2 = ||A^* x||_2$.

I know how to do this when $A$ is unitary. My approach. There exists a $y$ such that $x = Ay$. $||x||_2 = ||Ay||_2 = ||\sum_{i=1}^n y_i a_i||=\sum_{i=1}^n |y_i|$. Where $a_i$ are the orthonormal columns of $A$. But $||A^* x||_2 =||A^*  \sum_{i=1}^n y_i a_i||_2 = ||y||_2$. But this is incorrect, where am I going wrong?

Comment: What kind of matrix $AA^{*}$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not incorrect, you just need to show that $\|Ay\|= \|y\|$, if you let $C_1, ..., C_n$ be the columns of $A$ and $y=(y_1, ..., y_n)$, then 
$\|Ay\| = \|C_1 y_1 + ... +C_n y_n \| = y_1^2 + ... + y_n^2 = \|y\|$ since the $C_i$ are orthonormal.